# image manipulation component missing / image source url missing in https CKEditor in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ckeditor, ckfinder

I get 'image source url missing' or 'It was not possible to complete the request (Error unable to find an image manipulation component)' when I try to upload images in CKEditor text box.

This only happens when I run the site in a https environment, when I use http I do not have this issue.

Is there a config issue somewhere?

Comment: please provide some code and a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem appears when you try to make CK work in an ASP environment with Asp.Net thumbnails feature and SS, the function AspNetUrl that can be found in Image.asp and ckfinder.asp has the following line:

```
If UCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "ON") Then
```

that should be changed to:

```
If UCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) = "ON" Then
```